# Having multiple ASP.NET MVC3 projects share a common layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm completely new to the world of ASP.NET, C#, and the MVC framework.   At the company I work for we are finally upgrading from an ASP Classic environment to one where we can develop in ASP.NET.  There are currently two developers working on this intranet site.  Unfortunately using any type of version/source control is out of the question at least for now.

The two of us support many different departments each with their own webpages and online forms.   All of these departments share a common layout, css and some javascript.

My thought process is to setup each department as a separate MVC project and try to keep the meat of them separated that way.  In doing that how can I setup the layout, css and javascipt components that will be shared among each project?  I would still like to be able to make global changes to the colors ect without having to modify the files in 50 different projects.

Comment: How many projects are you thinking of making? If each department has a small number of pages/forms they need it may be beneficial to keep it one project. That way you never have to worry about worry about syncing changes to your base layout/js.

Comment: @Esteban There are quite a number of different departments that will probably need their own project file.  Another way to think of it is that we have a lot of different applications all housed on the same server that share the common layout but perform very different functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is MVC Areas: they " let you organize a large project into multiple smaller sections in order to manage the complexity of a large Web application." ([1](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/what-is-new-in-aspnet-mvc#_TOC3_2))

Check out this [walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee307987%28VS.100%29.aspx) to get familiar with areas and related concepts.

Answer (score 0):

My model for our intranet, (which works for me, your mileage may vary) is to create a common layout that & put that in a shared folder. This layout looks like a master page

For each app that we support, we create a master page, usually called global.master that has one line in it `. We then create another master page that uses the global.master as it's master page where we re-declare the content sections & add any css, javscript. layout, etc specific to the app in question.

This approach, using server-side includes has allowed me to make global changes across the entire site by changing the parent file, whilst keeping the individual apps themselves within their own app-pools.

Server-side includes are old school, but work well for us.